# Running AppEngine App in Development Server locally

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, maven

I am following this tutorial to build an AppEngine program: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/setup using the terminal on mac os x 64 bit

I am having trouble getting the "guestbook" app to run on the develoment server locally. When I run the program and try to open it in my web browser it crashes a Can anyone help me solve this?

I believe due this validation error:

```
  [INFO] Caused by: com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineConfigException: XML errorvalidating /Users/jamesjohnson/guestbook/guestbook-ear/target/guestbook-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT/META-INF/appengine-application.xml against /Users/jamesjohnson/.m2/repository/com/google/appengine/appengine-java-sdk/1.9.8/appengine-java-sdk/appengine-java-sdk-1.9.8/docs/appengine-application.xsd
```

per the instructions of the tutorial I have my build environment set to the following:

3.1.1 installed and pointed to by M2_HOME variable,
running java 7 and have the JAVA_HOME variable pointing to the correct jdk, and
the M2 variable set to M2_HOME/bin

I have created and configured the project exactly as the directions stated.

when I build the app  I get a BUILD SUCESS message:

then when I try to run the app in the development server on my local machine by invoking this command:

mvn appengine:devserver

the server begins to run:

```
[INFO] <<< appengine-maven-plugin:1.9.8:devserver (default-cli) @ guestbook-ear <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- appengine-maven-plugin:1.9.8:devserver (default-cli) @ guestbook-ear ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] Google App Engine Java SDK - Running Development Server
[INFO]
```

then I get an error message that says:

```
[INFO] com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineConfigException: Invalid configuration
```

followed by about 30 lines describing all the classes that failed. and at the end I still get a BUILD SUCCESS MESSAGE:

```
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.180s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Aug 07 16:44:35 MDT 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 11M/183M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I will post the entire error trace below:

Jamess-MacBook-Pro-2:guestbook-ear jamesjohnson$ mvn appengine:devserver

```
    [INFO] Scanning for projects...
    [INFO]                                                                         
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Building guestbook-ear 1.0-SNAPSHOT
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] >>> appengine-maven-plugin:1.9.8:devserver (default-cli) @ guestbook-ear >>>
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-ear-plugin:2.8:generate-application-xml (default-generate-application-xml) @      guestbook-ear ---
    [INFO] Generating application.xml
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3:resources (default-resources) @ guestbook-ear ---
    [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
    [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/jamesjohnson/guestbook/guestbook- ear/src/main/resources
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-ear-plugin:2.8:ear (default-ear) @ guestbook-ear ---
    [INFO] Copying artifact [war:com.google.appengine.demos:guestbook-war:1.0-SNAPSHOT] to [guestbook-war-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war] (unpacked)
    [INFO] Copy ear sources to /Users/jamesjohnson/guestbook/guestbook-ear/target/guestbook-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT
    [INFO] Including custom manifest file [/Users/jamesjohnson/guestbook/guestbook-ear/target/guestbook-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF]
    [INFO] Building jar: /Users/jamesjohnson/guestbook/guestbook-ear/target/guestbook-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT.ear
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] <<< appengine-maven-plugin:1.9.8:devserver (default-cli) @ guestbook-ear <<<
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- appengine-maven-plugin:1.9.8:devserver (default-cli) @ guestbook-ear ---
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] Google App Engine Java SDK - Running Development Server
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] Retrieving Google App Engine Java SDK from Maven
    [INFO] Running /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_67.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java -XstartOnFirstThread -D--enable_all_permissions=true -Xbootclasspath/p:/Users/jamesjohnson/.m2/repository/com/google/appengine/appengine-java-sdk/1.9.8/appengine-java-sdk/appengine-java-sdk-1.9.8/lib/override/appengine-dev-jdk-overrides.jar -Dappengine.fullscan.seconds=5 -classpath /Users/jamesjohnson/.m2/repository/com/google/appengine/appengine-java-sdk/1.9.8/appengine-java-sdk/appengine-java-sdk-1.9.8/lib/appengine-tools-api.jar com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain --allow_remote_shutdown --no_java_agent /Users/jamesjohnson/guestbook/guestbook-ear/target/guestbook-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT
    [INFO] com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineConfigException: Invalid configuration

    [INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.reportDeferredConfigurationException(DevAppServerImpl.java:474)

    [INFO]  at     com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.doStart(DevAppServerImpl.java:226)
    [INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.access$000(DevAppServerImpl.java:47)

    [INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl$1.run(DevAppServerImpl.java:213)
    [INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl$1.run(DevAppServerImpl.java:211)
    [INFO]  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

    [INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:211)
    [INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply(DevAppServerMain.java:277)
    [INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.util.Parser$ParseResult.applyArgs(Parser.java:48)
    [INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.run(DevAppServerMain.java:219)

    [INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main(DevAppServerMain.java:210)          

    [INFO] Caused by: com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineConfigException: XML error validating /Users/jamesjohnson/guestbook/guestbook-ear/target/guestbook-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT/META-INF/appengine-application.xml against /Users/jamesjohnson/.m2/repository/com/google/appengine/appengine-java-sdk/1.9.8/appengine-java-sdk/appengine-java-sdk-1.9.8/docs/appengine-application.xsd

    [INFO]  at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.EarHelper.validateXml(EarHelper.java:253)
    [INFO]  at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.EarHelper.readEarInfo(EarHelper.java:108)
    [INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApplicationConfigurationManager.readEarConfiguration(ApplicationConfigurationManager.java:203)
    [INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApplicationConfigurationManager.<init> (ApplicationConfigurationManager.java:150)

    [INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApplicationConfigurationManager.newEarConfigurationManager(ApplicationConfigurationManager.java:66)
    [INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApplicationConfigurationManager.newEarConfigurationManager(ApplicationConfigurationManager.java:53)
    [INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.<init>(DevAppServerImpl.java:132)
    [INFO]  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

    [INFO]  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    [INFO]  at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    [INFO]  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    [INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory.doCreateDevAppServer(DevAppServerFactory.java:258)
    [INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory.access$000(DevAppServerFactory.java:36)
    [INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$1.run(DevAppServerFactory.java:226)
    [INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$1.run(DevAppServerFactory.java:224)

    [INFO]  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    [INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory.createDevAppServer(DevAppServerFactory.java:224)
   [INFO]   at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory.createDevAppServer(DevAppServerFactory.java:94)
    [INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply(DevAppServerMain.java:265)
   [INFO]   ... 3 more
   [INFO] Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.
   [INFO]   at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:198)
   [INFO]   at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:177)
   [INFO]   at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:441)
   [INFO]   at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:368)
   [INFO]   at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(XMLScanner.java:1436)
   [INFO]   at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:999)
   [INFO]   at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
    [INFO]  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:117)
    [INFO]  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
    [INFO]  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
    [INFO]  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
    [INFO]  at c   om.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.validation.StreamValidatorHelper.validate(StreamValidatorHelper.java:155)
    [INFO]  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.validation.ValidatorImpl.validate(ValidatorImpl.java:116)
    [INFO]  at javax.xml.validation.Validator.validate(Validator.java:124)
    [INFO]  at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.EarHelper.validateXml(EarHelper.java:250)
    [INFO]  ... 21 more
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 3.180s
    [INFO] Finished at: Thu Aug 07 16:44:35 MDT 2014
    [INFO] Final Memory: 11M/183M
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in your `appengine-application.xml` file. The code and trace you listed in your question is not related to this problem.

Comment: Thanks! ok, how did you discover that, and how can I fix it?

Comment: It can be something as small as a missing closing tag or a typo. We can't help without looking at the code.

Comment: here are the contents of appengine-application.xml

Comment: ?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<appengine-application xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
  <application>single-loop-665 </application>
</appengine-application>

Comment: I don't see an opening `<`. Plus, I use `appengine-web-app` instead of `appengine-application`, but I don't know if it makes any difference.

Comment: the opening < is present in the actual file, I missed it while copy-pasting. should I simply rename the file appengine-web-app?

Comment: I could not find explanation why some projects have `appengine-web.xml` file and other projects have `appengine-application.xml` file with basically the same content. My file also includes `<version>1</version>` tag, but I don't know if it's required. By the way, you don't need a semi-colon after any of the tags - again, I don't know if it caused your error.

Comment: ok, thanks for looking at my issue Andrei. I'll post the answer when I  solve it.

Comment: Ok I think I have the discovered the real issue. There is an opening < that is missing from the appengine-application.xml file. I thought I had a edited it however, for some reason I can't get the change to persist. I have edited the file multiple times using the vi- vim- nano- as a root user. I also edited and saved the file using a gui editor.  Each time I do a clean install of maven I think the files are being automatically regenerated with the error. How can I cause this edit to persisit?

Comment: *CORRECTION* the files are actually regenerated when I run the application, not when I do an install of maven.